# How to downgrade to a specific version of package in linux mint?

Tags: thunderbird, apt, downgrade

I've recently upgraded thunderbird to version 68.2, which broke every single addon I had, so I decided to downgrade to version 60.9, specifically, `apt-cache policy thunderbird` showed me that a possible version was `1:60.9.0+build1-0ubuntu0.18.04.1`, so I happily downgraded and it was all fine with my addons back.

Yesterday, however, I updated by mistake thunderbird and nothing works once again. So I tried to do the same thing, but unfortunately version 60.9 is not available anymore! `apt-cache policy thunderbird` only shows two versions:

```
thunderbird:
  Installed: 1:52.7.0+build1-0ubuntu1
  Candidate:  1:68.2.1+build1-0ubuntu0.18.04.1
  Tabella versione:
     1:68.2.1+build1-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 500
        500 http://it-mirrors.evowise.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/main amd64 Packages
 *** 1:52.7.0+build1-0ubuntu1 500
        500 http://it-mirrors.evowise.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

And of course installing it anyway does not work

```
$ sudo apt install thunderbird=1:60.9.0+build1-0ubuntu1
Reading package list... Done
Generating dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Version "1:60.9.0+build1-0ubuntu1" for "thunderbird" not found
```

I've tried install 52.7 but it's way too old and incompatible with my profile, but I can't get back to 68.2 because none of my (fundamental) addons work. Can I manually download somewhere the version I need?

Comment: It looks like the 60.x version has been completely removed from the Ubuntu repos; I couldn't even find it on the main Thunderbird site. You might be able to find a 3rd-party site that still has that version.

Comment: It might be useful to add a list of the extensions that are no longer working.  Even if you can find an old version of Thunderbird, the add-on authors often stop supporting the deprecated versions.  People may be able to suggest good replacement add-ons that work with current releases of Thunderbird.

Comment: Mostly it's just startup master. Without it there's an incredibly annoying but in TB where master password is requested multiple times (as much as 4) and this is quite irritating and time-consuming. Then some more I needed (like cardbook) actually got updated, but I would like my theme back